Problem with unnumbered theorem
I would like to include an unnumbered theorem in my text. According to what I read, one needs to define a theorem environment using \newtheorem* instead of the usual \newtheorem. However, this seems to cause problems with the settings I am using. Here is a minimal example showing the cause of the problem.
\documentclass[8pt,openany]{book} 
\usepackage[vvarbb,ebgaramond,smallerops]{newtx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>=stealth}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{test}[theorem]{\normalfont\scshape Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{test}
    The following statement is true.
\end{test}
\end{document}

Any help concerning this issue would be of great help.

Off-topic: 8pt isn't an option for book. You are actually getting 10pt if you do this.

Note that I deleted the newtheorem tag because you're using amsthm rather than that package, even though amsthm provides a \newtheorem macro ....

Probably what you want:
\documentclass[openany]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[vvarbb,ebgaramond,smallerops]{newtx}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz, diagrams={>=stealth}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem*{test}{\normalfont\scshape Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{test}
    The following statement is true.
\end{test}
\end{document}


\newtheorem*{test}{\normalfont\scshape Theorem}. You don't want [theorem] because that's for a counter but you aren't numbering these, so \newtheorem doesn't support it.
You're also getting an earlier error about \openbox which reordering the packages in the preamble solves.
8pt is not a valid option for book, so you're getting 10pt, which is the default anyway.

